# How to create a line diagram with non-linear date points?

Tags: iwork-numbers

I have a spreadsheet with numerical data like this:

```
01.01.2011 | Val1 | Val2 | Val3
03.01.2011 | Val1 | Val2 | Val3
03.01.2011 | Val1 | Val2 | Val3
05.02.2011 | Val1 | Val2 | Val3
17.02.2011 | Val1 | Val2 | Val3
03.04.2011 | Val1 | Val2 | Val3
```

As you see, the first three measurements are close together (by date). How do I make a line diagram in which the x-coordinates of the dates are sized correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Is this something suited to using a scatter plot rather than a line plot in iWork: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3347